# Which Method will get override from interface or class?

Tags: java, oop

In the below program I had extended Demo1 class and implemented Demo interface and in Practice class I override `public void demo()` which was declared in both class and interface then from which that method will get Override? and why?

```
 interface Demo{
        void demo();
    }

class Demo1{
    int i=10;
    public void demo() {
       System.out.println("this is demo"+i);
    }
}
public class practice extends Demo1 implements Demo {
    public static void Main(String[] args ) {
        practice p=new practice();
        p.demo();
               
    }
    
    public void demo() {
        System.out.println("This is Overrided method");
    }
}
```

Comment: Both, because it has to.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that it doesn't matter. What the compiler is is looking for is that the signature of the abstract interface method is implemented in your class, or inherited from a supertype (and it doesn't care whether that inherited signature was meant to implement the abstract method in question). 
And whether your `demo()` method is called on a `practice` object declared as `Demo` or `Demo1` is also irrelevant the method signature is implemented either way.

You can, in fact, even remove your `demo()` override (assuming you didn't need to change the behavior), and the code would still compile:

```
class practice extends Demo1 implements Demo {
    public static void Main(String[] args) {
        practice p = new practice();
        p.demo();
    }
}
```

That is, even if `Demo1.demo()` has nothing to do with `Demo.demo()`, the fact that `practice` inherits `Demo1.demo()` which has the same signature as `Demo.demo()` and without violating access and exception constraints, that makes `practice` a valid implementation of `Demo`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I get it  where I was making a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Method from interface is not **overrided**, it's **implemented**.

Your **practice** class **inherits** the **demo** method from **Demo1** class and this method will be used to **implement** Demo **interface** method if you omit the implementation of demo method in **practice** class itself.

Since you implement the **demo** method in **practice** class itself - this method **overrides** the method from **Demo1** class and also **implements** the method from **Demo** interface

Answer (score 0):

If you run the below code

```
public class practice extends Demo1 implements Demo {
public static void main(String[] args ) {
    practice p=new practice();
    p.demo();
           
}

public void demo() {
    System.out.println("This is Overrided method");
}
}
```

Output will be  "This is Override method" and if you comment the demo method like below

```
public class practice extends Demo1 implements Demo {
public static void main(String[] args ) {
    practice p=new practice();
    p.demo();
           
}

/*public void demo() {
    System.out.println("This is Overrided method");
}*/
}
```

Output will be "this is demo10". In first case as class object finds definition of demo in self, it will give preference to this over to parent class.

Answer (score 0):

Demo1 is providing implemetation of demo(). so it will take parent demo() method. Output will be

> this is demo10

But then you have implemented again overriding of demo() method in child class **practice**

so output is now

> This is Overrided method